# WPF resize image

Tags: wpf, image, image-resizing

I want to show many images on window on size not more than 245px * 135px, images can be in different size, so, I want to resize images, which have at least width > 245 or height > 135. I try to do it :

```
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(filepath);
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.EndInit();

                if (bi.Width > bi.Height)
                {
                    bi.DecodePixelHeight = Convert.ToInt32(bi.Height * (245 / bi.Width));
                    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 245;
                }
                else
                {
                    bi.DecodePixelWidth = Convert.ToInt32(bi.Width * (135 / bi.Height));
                    bi.DecodePixelHeight = 135;
                }
```

but DecodePixelXXX is 0, because I should do it before EndIint(). But I can't do it before EndInit, because I don't know Width/Height yet. How to do it without loading a whole image to BitmapImage with max performance?

Comment: Why not just set the size of the Image controls instead of the BitmapImages?

Comment: I don't want to load big pictures to memory.

Comment: How many images are you going to load? Are you actually encountering a memory problem?

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Just another note for perfectionists: it is not necessary to set both `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight`, as BitmapImage will automatically keep the aspect ratio of the image. Hence you only need to set `bi.DecodePixelWidth = 245` or `bi.DecodePixelHeight = 135` respectively, and may drop the `Convert.ToInt32(...)` stuff. But you will have to load the image twice in order to make your approach work.